# Функция лайк для других блоков

Tags: javascript

помогите решить (господи помилуй)
есть 6 кнопок лайк нажимаю на 1 цвет меняется на другую(это работает)
почему то для других оставшиеся он не хочет работать

https://codepen.io/Covid-19-create/pen/KKdEqbw

```js
const like = document.querySelector('.element__heart')
like.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.target.classList.toggle('element__heart_like')
});
```

```css
.element__heart {
    margin: 31px 22px 30px 0;
    
    background-color: red;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    width: 21px;
    height: 18px;
}

.element__heart_like {
    background-color: green;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
<button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
<button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
<button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
<button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
<button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) выбирает только первый элемент, который соответствует селектору, для выбора всех элементов, соответствующих селектору следует использовать [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Таким образом JS код в вашем случае должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
const like = document.querySelectorAll('.element__heart');
like.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      evt.target.classList.toggle('element__heart_like');
  });
});
```

Comment: При использовании `function()` можно использовать контекст `this`

Answer (score 0):

В случаях со списками лучше использовать делегирование - вешать обработчик клика на родительский элемент и проверять событие по event.target

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.buttons-wrap')

wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('element__heart')){
      e.target.classList.toggle('element__heart_like')
    }
});
```

```css
.element__heart {
    margin: 31px 22px 30px 0;
    
    background-color: red;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    width: 21px;
    height: 18px;
}

.element__heart_like {
    background-color: green;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-wrap">
  <button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
  <button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
  <button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
  <button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
  <button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
  <button class="element__heart" type="button"></button>
</div>
```